# How to convert a i18n.map to a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem.
I developed a web app that converts a json file into a table.
The problem arises when instead of json I have a file like this:

```
  i18n.map("it", {
errors: {
 "cannot.fetch.credit":"Ops... non riesco a leggere il credito.",
 "not.enough.credit.to.buy":"Non hai abbastanza credito per comprare  questo biglietto."
},
status: {
    title: "Il tuo stato",
    scanqrbus: "Inquadra il QR code all'interno del bus",
    tickets: {
        title: "Biglietto"
    }
},
offline: {
    connectionless: "Connessione assente",
    reconnect: "Riconnetti",
    nostart: "Puoi prenotare biglietti solo quando la connessione è attiva",
    nosignup: "Connessione assente"
}});
```

There is a way to convert that file type in a json like this using javascript?

```
    {
"errors": {
 "cannot.fetch.credit":"Ops... non riesco a leggere il credito.",
 "not.enough.credit.to.buy":"Non hai abbastanza credito per comprare questo biglietto."
},
"status": {
    "title": "Il tuo stato",
    "scanqrbus": "Inquadra il QR code all'interno del bus",
    "tickets": {
        "title": "Biglietto"
    }
},
"offline": {
    "connectionless": "Connessione assente",
    "reconnect": "Riconnetti",
    "nostart": "Puoi prenotare biglietti solo quando la connessione è attiva",
    "nosignup": "Connessione assente"
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to load your i18n.map file into a string, you could use the following function.

**You should be very careful when using this function. It uses `eval` and will execute any code that is passed to it as a parameter.**

```
function i18nToJSON (i18nstring) {
    var i18n = {};
    i18n.map = function (lang, obj) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    };
    return eval(i18nstring);
}
```

Example use:

```
var x = 'i18n.map("it", {a: "123", b: "456"});';
var JSONstring = i18nToJSON(x);
console.log (JSONstring);                  // {"a":"123","b":"456"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , you've been a big help.

Comment: Do you now how can i convert the json to a i18n string?

Comment: @LeonardoMidolo 
Sorry, I can't help you with that. The request to _convert json to i18n string_ is too vague and general. In fact, the i18n.map "string" in your question is actually a call of an `i18n.map` function. It seems that you are working with something related to [this internationalization package](https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-i18n). You might want to read its documentation and perhaps use it.  To get an object from JSON string, use `JSON.parse(string)`.

Comment: @PeterSr  Basically what I want to do is ( after changing the values ​​)  return the same string as  original. Es: --> var tmp='i18n.map("it", {
errors: {ecc....);'